# How to set a fixed range to the KDChart BarDiagram?

Tags: c++, qt

I want to display a BarDiagram using the `KDChart` library. The vertical values shall be between -120 to 0.

Normally, KDChart starts the bars at 0 as the follow png shows:
   [Bar Diagram with 0 on top and -120 at the bottom, with the bars growing from 0 towards -120 http://bvdpi.img36.wal8.com/img36/371522_20130905114637/137835282162.png](http://bvdpi.img36.wal8.com/img36/371522_20130905114637/137835282162.png)

Now `KDChart::CartesianCoordinatePlane` has a method `setVerticalRangeReversed(bool)`.

After calling the method, the diagram looks like this:
[Bar Diagram with -120 on top and 0 at the bottom, with the bars growing from 0 towards -120 http://bvdpi.img36.wal8.com/img36/371522_20130905114637/137835282217.png](http://bvdpi.img36.wal8.com/img36/371522_20130905114637/137835282217.png)

What I need is a mix of both, where the bars are like in the bottom picture, but the Y Axis is like in the upper picture.
Is there any way in KDChart to let the bars start at -120 and grow towards 0?

Comment: I don't know the solution for this, but I rewrote the question to make it easier for others to understand what you are trying to achieve. Re-edit this if I got your problem wrong.

Comment: If you still don't have a solution, you could try using the bottom approach and subclassing [CartesianAxis](http://docs.kdab.com/kdchart/2.4.1/class_k_d_chart_1_1_cartesian_axis.html) and drawing the axis yourself

Comment: Thanks，I had a solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the range of the axis manually using:

```
CartesianCoordinatePlane::setVerticalRange(const QPair< qreal, qreal > & range)
```

So your code would look like this:

```
static_cast<CartesianCoordinatePlane*>(chart->coordinatePlane())->setVerticalRange(qMakePair(-120,0));
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the y axis values has min value -120, I convert the values from [-120,0] to [0, 120],
by each value plus abs(-120).

```
    value += abs(-120);
```

Also we must convert the y axis ticks, CartesianAxis has a interface  setAnnotations(QMap). So I made a map like this:

```
    QMap<double, QString> m;
    m.insert(0, "-120");
    m.insert(20, "-100");
    m.insert(60, "-60");
    //...
    m.insert(120, "0");
    yAxis->setAnnotations(m);
```

Now, the chart looks normally:

Comment: As a side node: `value += abs(-120)` is the same as `value += 120`